Do almost all Gibbs' measures satisfy the weak-Poincare Inequality?
I am trying to interprete the discussion given in  Section 3 of this paper,
https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82217936.pdf
Lets suppose we restrict to considering Gibbs's measures of the form $\sim e^{-V}$.

Then is there any easy sufficient condition on $V$ which ensures that this Gibbs' measure is weak-PI ?

Is there an analogue of "Miclo's trick" here that if $V = V_1 + V_2$ with $V_1$ being "nice" and $V_2$ being strongly-convex would ensure that this Gibbs' measure is weak PI?



Anything with log-concave tails and 'reasonable' bulk behaviour (e.g. density bounded away from 0 and infinity on compact sets) will even satisfy a 'genuine' PI; the interest of WPIs in this context is mostly to accommodate probability measures with heavier tails. The conditions for some (non-quantitative) WPI to hold are indeed very weak, e.g. if V is locally bounded and the support is connected, as RW say in the linked paper. Are you looking for something more refined than this?

Thanks! Actually I am not able to see how even this much can be read from this Section 3, that "as long as V is locally bounded and has a connected support then e^(-V) is Gibbs'". Can you really prove this from whatever is said in this Section 3?

Would it be sufficient for me to justify Remark 1 on Page 573? The argument is roughly that i) such estimates hold for uniform measures over reasonable compact sets, ii) for locally-bounded $V$, $V$ will be bounded uniformly above and below on such sets, and hence iii) by usual transfer principles (similar to e.g. Holley-Stroock), one can inherit the same estimates for $\exp(-V)$ on the same set.
